# My CacheWarmup has 99 files but mine ain't one

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

### My CacheWarmup has 99 files but mine ain't one!

Lately (I feel as of Symfony 6.3) we have been getting this error randomly when deploying the application and the cache is warmed up.

> CRITICAL  [console] Error thrown while running command "cache:warmup --no-debug". Message: "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\CacheWarmer\ProxyCacheWarmer::warmUp()" should return a list of files or classes but "/path/to/project/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__SalesDomainDocumentLineProductImageLineProductImageLine.php.cc2702163296ea1613bb4ab4" is none of them." ["exception" => LogicException { …},"command" => "cache:warmup --no-debug","message" => ""Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\CacheWarmer\ProxyCacheWarmer::warmUp()" should return a list of files or classes but "/path/to/project/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__SalesDomainDocumentLineProductImageLineProductImageLine.php.cc2702163296ea1613bb4ab4" is none of them."]

In this case it is about `__CG__SalesDomainDocumentLineProductImageLineProductImageLine.php.cc2702163296ea1613bb4ab4`, but this is a different file every time.

I have no idea how to (steadily) reproduce it as it doesn't always happen and never happens in dev environment. When Googeling this error, there are not many results let alone helpful ones.

I tried looking to the `ProxyCacheWarmer::warmUp()`-method, but besides telling me what the exception already told me, I don't see much helpful their either.

- How to debug?
- What could be the cause?